# Async/Await Clarification in Swift: does this code successfully run the two network requests asynchronously?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, async-await

The below function does three things...

1. Get the timezone of a location
2. Get the weather for a location
3. Do something with the timezone and location data

The timezone fetch and the weather fetch are both requests that can take some time... I'd like them to run concurrently. I'd also like to be confident that I can safely operate on the timezone and weather data once it has arrived.

Does this code accomplish that? How can it be improved to be more readable?

```
func getWeather() async {
    do {
        
        async let grabWeather = WeatherService.shared.weather(for: self.location)
        async let grabPlacemarks = CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(self.location)
        
        weather = try await grabWeather
        guard let grabTimezone = try await grabPlacemarks.first?.timeZone else {
            print("Error – no timezone")
            return
        }
        timezone = grabTimezone
        

        // Do something with timezone and weather below
        // ...

        
    } catch {
        fatalError("\(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes they run concurrently.

Comment: Please read the corresponding paragraph [Calling Asynchronous Functions in Parallel](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/concurrency/#Calling-Asynchronous-Functions-in-Parallel) in the Language Guide. A bit more readable is `getWeather() async throws` and `throw` an error if `grabTimezone` fails.

Answer (score 0):

You ask:

> does this code accomplish that [concurrent execution]?

Yes. It is the entire purpose of `async let`. See [SE-0317](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0317-async-let.md) or [Calling Asynchronous Functions in Parallel](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/concurrency/#Calling-Asynchronous-Functions-in-Parallel).

> How can it be improved … ?

A few observations:

1. One does not want to crash the app with `fatalError` if one of those services fails. We should just throw the error and let the caller update its UI with the localized error message.
2. The “grab” variable names don’t follow standard conventions and the code can be simplified to render them unnecessary.

That yields something simpler, e.g.:

```swift
func getWeather() async throws {
    async let placemarks = CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location)
    let weather = try await WeatherService.shared.weather(for: location)

    guard let timeZone = try await placemarks.first?.timeZone else {
        throw WeatherError.noTimeZone
    }
    
    // Do something with timezone and weather below ...
}
```

Needless to say, it still runs these concurrently.

Where:

```swift
enum WeatherError: Error {
    case noTimeZone
}

extension WeatherError: LocalizedError {
    var errorDescription: String {
        switch self {
            case .noTimeZone: return NSLocalizedString("Unable to identify timezone of the desired location.", comment: "WeatherError")
        }
    }
}
```